# How to locate and replace a value

Tags: coldfusion

I have been looking for a solution for the following:

Replace the `<` with the words less than, but keep the number `<xx` (the `xx` is a number like 55). For example: `<55` or `< 55` to `less than 55`.

I have not found a solution.

Mike

Comment: have you looked at the replace function? https://helpx.adobe.com/uk/coldfusion/cfml-reference/coldfusion-functions/functions-m-r/replace.html

Comment: The example would be: <55 or < 55 and replace with less than 55.

Comment: *I have not found a solution.* Don't take this the wrong way, but it's hard to believe a five second google search on "ColdFusion replace value" didn't turn up the [replace()](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) function ;-) Since I'm sure you searched before posting, there must be something wrong with the code and/or result that we're not aware of, so please take a minute to [edit] your question and provide more details and include your code and any error messages. (Improving your question is encouraged on S.O.) See also [ask].

Answer (score 1):

## The naive way

...would be just using [`replace()`](https://helpx.adobe.com/coldfusion/cfml-reference/coldfusion-functions/functions-m-r/replace.html) and call it a day:

```
<cfscript>

    s = "Is 54 < 55 and < 56?";

    r = replace(s, "<", "less than", "ALL");
    writeOutput(r);

</cfscript>
```

Returns: `Is 54 less than 55 and less than 56?`

## But it's not that easy

...because you eventually encounter:

```
<cfscript>

    s = "Is 54<55 and <56?";

    r = replace(s, "<", "less than", "ALL");
    writeOutput(r);

</cfscript>
```

Returns: `Is 54less than55 and less than56?`

We need to handle missing whitespaces around `<`.
Easy, we just add spaces around the needle, like this `" less than "`.

## Are we done?

...No, it can always get worse. Look at this:

```
<cfscript>

    s = "Is <b>54</b><55 and < 56?";

    r = replace(s, "<", " less than ", "ALL");
    writeOutput(r);

</cfscript>
```

Returns: `Is  less than b>54 less than /b> less than 55 and  less than  56?`

We need to actually detect if the `>` character is in front of a digit.

## The fix

...is called regular expression. And [`reReplace()`](https://helpx.adobe.com/coldfusion/cfml-reference/coldfusion-functions/functions-m-r/rereplace.html) the name of the function we need:

```
<cfscript>

    s = "Is <b>54</b> <55 and < 56?";

    r = reReplace(s, "<\s*([0-9])", "less than \1", "ALL");
    writeOutput(r);

</cfscript>
```

Returns: `Is <b>54</b> less than 55 and less than 56?`

Breakdown of the regex:

- `<`
  pattern starts with `<`
- `\s*`
  any whitespace (`\s`), can be missing or present in any number (`*`)
- `([0-9])`
  we are capturing any digit `[0-9]` using brackets

In the needle we replace everything that was not captured with `less than` and bring back the captured digit using `\1`. As a sideffect, we also removed any additional whitespaces in front of the digit, since we only captured the digit itself and replaced everything between `<` and the digit.

You could preserve the whitespaces in front by extending the capture and there also might be a need to tackle something like `54< 55` to result in `54 less than 55`. Once you understand how regex capturing works, this won't be a problem for you.